# How to get full URL inside canLoad() method?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a Guard which implements canLoad interface.
And I want to get full url to create link to return back after authentication.
But if URL looks like *'/parent/children'*

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanLoad {  
  canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) {
      console.log(route.path, segments[0].path); //children, children
  }
}
```

router:

```
{
  path: 'children',
  loadChildren: ()=> import(path-to-module).then((m)=> m.Module),
  canLoad: [MyGuard]
}
```

it returns me only *'/children'* part of URL.

How can I get full URL *'/parent/children'* inside canLoad method?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanLoad {  
  canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) {
      const fullPath = segments.reduce((path, currSegment) => {
        return `${path}/${currSegment.path}`;
      }, '');
      console.log("fullPath", fullPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no *'parent'* part of URL inside segments. console.log("fullPath", fullPath); // children